# Reference Based on Two Fields of a Content Type

Tags: entities, nodes

I have two content types `account` and `device`. `device` has a reference field named `reference_account_number` and it's referencing `account_number` in `account`, but the unique key for `account` is a composite key `account_number` and `environment`.

I used auto node title module to generate the node title based on `account_number` for `account`, and let `reference_account_number` map on to the node title of the `account` nodes.
So my problem comes up when I try to do feed import when there are duplicate `account_number` but different `environment`. The `reference_account_number` only map onto the `account` node that has matching node title.

Is there any way to reference another node based on two fields?
I was thinking about adding a `environment` field to `device` content type as well

Ideally, I would like this scenario happens when a user creates a new `device` content.

*User enters the `account number` and `environment`, upon completion, user views the content just created, and `reference account number` provides a link to all existing `account` that matches the `account number` user inputted for the `device` content, same thing goes for `environment`*

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you could not just reconfigure auto node title to generate a node title based on a composit account number and environment -- say, something like "[account_number] ([environment])"?  It seems like if you did this, then your reference_account_number configuration would remain unchanged, your feeds will not get confused, and users can still add references by typing the account number only thanks to the standard autocomplete feature of node references.

If you did not like the way that "[account_number] ([environment])" looks in the output of your site, you could alter the render array, maybe in a hook_process_field.  For a good description on hooking the Drupal 7 render process, see [The Scary Render Array](http://cocoate.com/ddbook/scary-render-array).

Comment: Yea, I thought about that. But I have a php file that generate xml file from these two content types. This would be a problem since I don't wanna print out the title in this case.

Comment: I am not sure under what conditions you do not want to print the title.  If you mean that you do not want the title to appear in the xml, the feeds module will, I believe, allow you to easily fix up the node at import time. So, you should be able to regenerate the title from the account number and environment before node_save is called, which should make your references work out. Of course, this means that your reference account number in your device xml would be "[account_number] ([environment])"; hopefully this is okay, because I think it would be a lot harder to make a two-field relation.

Comment: Yea, I don't want reference account number displaying both account number and environment. I can just make no reference at all, and the xml will output just fine, but I can't make a view based on the relationship. I tried [field reference](http://drupal.org/project/field_reference), it can reference fields, but it's not good since I have to use feeds importer to import csv file